# iOS 11 Crash on EventKitUI -[EKCalendarChooser _selectAllCalendarsAndStores:]

Tags: ios11, eventkit

This crash only happens on iOS 11, I have no idea how to fix it.

The crash happens when tapping on the [Show All] button on the new toolbar for iOS 11's EKCalendarChooser class, but while it's selectionStyle set to `.single`:

Fatal Exception: **NSInternalInconsistencyException** **Invalid style**

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1830e3d38 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1825f8528 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1830e3c0c +[NSException raise:format:]
3  Foundation                     0x183a72c24 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:]
4  EventKitUI                     0x1941ad908 -[EKCalendarChooser _selectAllCalendarsAndStores:]
5  EventKitUI                     0x1941a6384 -[EKCalendarChooser showAllButtonPressed]
6  UIKit                          0x18c52820c -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
7  UIKit                          0x18c68253c -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:]
8  UIKit                          0x18c52820c -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
9  UIKit                          0x18c52818c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]
10 UIKit                          0x18c512f4c -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]
11 UIKit                          0x18c5130b4 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]
12 UIKit                          0x18c527a80 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:]
13 UIKit                          0x18cb73ec8 _UIGestureEnvironmentSortAndSendDelayedTouches
14 UIKit                          0x18cb6f488 _UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate
15 CoreFoundation                 0x18308b8b8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
16 CoreFoundation                 0x183089270 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
17 CoreFoundation                 0x18308982c __CFRunLoopRun
18 CoreFoundation                 0x182faa2d8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
19 GraphicsServices               0x184e3bf84 GSEventRunModal
20 UIKit                          0x18c557880 UIApplicationMain
21 MyApp1                         0x104d92be4 main (AppDelegate.swift:15)
22 libdyld.dylib                  0x182ace56c start
```

I wonder is there a way to hide the new toolbar?

=====
Edited on 19 Nov 2017

Screenshot added to show the new toolbar:

Once the `selectedCalendars` is left empty, the new toolbar is showing. Once the button [Show All] taps, the crash occurs.

[image]

Comment: For those who have the same issue, you can specify a (new created) calendar for the selectedCalendars to prevent showing the new toolbar.

Comment: But I still don't know how to handle the [Show All] error if there is no selectedCalendars set.

Comment: I’m having a different, but also EKCalendarChooser related probelm on iOS 11.1 beta, crashng on presenting the view controller. It could be the iOS issue. https://www.google.co.jp/amp/s/9to5mac.com/2017/10/23/apple-releases-ios-11-1-beta-5-to-developers/amp/

Comment: The crash I'm getting is different, but seems to happen if I select all calendars rather than just writable calendars. Related issue? How do I see the Show All button you refer to? I see it only when the selection is multiple.

Comment: Hi @VictorEngel to have the iOS 11 toolbar, don't set `selectedCalendars` (or set it to nil), `selectionStyle` to `.single`, and only show the editable calendars, and you will see the bar.

Comment: Setting `selectedCalendars` to nil produces error `Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument`. Passing an empty set bypasses the error, but it also doesn't produce the bar. Also, that defeats the ability to show to the user what calendar may already be selected, so I consider that a poor solution.

Comment: Sorry @VictorEngel my bad - I meant to leave `selectedCalendars` empty. And you will have the toolbar showing - please see the original post edited.

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work unless I had multiple selected. I'm using Objective-C, not Swift, but I don't think that should matter. Anyway, using an empty set is not a good solution since, as I said, it doesn't show the user's previously selected calendar.

Comment: @VictorEngel in my app, if there is no previous selected calendar, I wouldn't select any (let the user decide), but if there is already selected one, I will use it. So it's not an issue for me. By the way, thanks for your suggestion. Nice considering.

Comment: I am facing the same problem as the OP. Did anyone find a solution yet which prevents the crash?

Comment: @user826955 Do not set an empty list to the `selectedCalendars` will hide the new toolbar.

Comment: Thanks, that somehow did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have encountered the same error and discovered a strange but surprisingly effective method of solving it. Turns out if you clear out the selected calendars set before presenting the view controller the toolbar disappears, thus protecting from the crash.

```
calendarChooser.selectedCalendars = Set();
```